# How to assign a parameter to a query to be emailed as output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to email results of a query as the body of an email. I'm using 2 stored procedures to accomplish this. The first stored procedure is a sample email code because SQL Server 2000 does not have a built in send mail feature like SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008.

Here is what I have so far for the stored procedure: I declare `@Body`, then assign `@Body` to the stored procedure `getpaidout1929` (`Exec @Body = sp_getpaidout1929`) which runs the query below.

```
SELECT        Store_Id, Paid_Out_Amount, Paid_Out_Comment, Paid_Out_Datetime, Update_UserName
FROM            Paid_Out_Tb
WHERE        (Store_Id = 1929) AND (Paid_Out_Amount > 50) AND (Paid_Out_Datetime BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                         '2012-06-30 00:00:00', 102))
```

I then execute the stored procedure.

```
Exec sp_SQLNotify ‘to@who.com', ‘who@who.com, ‘test’
```

It sends the email but has `0` as the body message.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SQLNotify] 
   @From varchar(100) ,
   @To varchar(100) ,
   @Subject varchar(100)=" "
   
/*********************************************************************

This stored procedure takes the above parameters and sends an e-mail. 
All of the mail configurations are hard-coded in the stored procedure. 
Comments are added to the stored procedure where necessary.
Reference to the CDOSYS objects are at the following MSDN Web site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cdosys/html/_cdosys_messaging.asp

***********************************************************************/ 
   AS
   Declare @iMsg int
   Declare @hr int
   Declare @source varchar(255)
   Declare @description varchar(500)
   Declare @output varchar(1000)
   Declare @Body Varchar (8000)
   


--************* Create the CDO.Message Object ************************
   EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'CDO.Message', @iMsg OUT

--***************Configuring the Message Object ******************
-- This is to configure a remote SMTP server.
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cdosys/html/_cdosys_schema_configuration_sendusing.asp
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing").Value','2'
-- This is to configure the Server Name or IP address. 
-- Replace MailServerName by the name or IP of your SMTP Server.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver").Value', '10.0.1.3' 

-- Save the configurations to the message object.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Configuration.Fields.Update', null
   Exec @Body = sp_getpaidout1929

-- Set the e-mail parameters.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'To', @To
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'From', @From
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Subject', @Subject

-- If you are using HTML e-mail, use 'HTMLBody' instead of 'TextBody'.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'TextBody', @Body
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Send', NULL

-- Sample error handling.
   IF @hr <>0 
     select @hr
     BEGIN
       EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetErrorInfo NULL, @source OUT, @description OUT
       IF @hr = 0
         BEGIN
           SELECT @output = '  Source: ' + @source
           PRINT  @output
           SELECT @output = '  Description: ' + @description
           PRINT  @output
         END
       ELSE
         BEGIN
           PRINT '  sp_OAGetErrorInfo failed.'
           RETURN
         END
     END

-- Do some error handling after each step if you need to.
-- Clean up the objects created.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @iMsg
   
   PRINT 'Mail Sent!'

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258848%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for executing a stored procedure? If you do this:

`exec @foo = dbo.SomeProc`

Then `@foo` contains the return status of the procedure, which in this case is zero for success.

And SQL 2000 does indeed have [built-in email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260697%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), so you could pass your stored procedure execution string as the `@query` parameter, to avoid having to convert a result set into a scalar value yourself.

You should also consider an external script in a language like Perl, PowerShell etc. because formatting and emailing data is neither easy nor flexible using a pure TSQL approach.

Comment: My SQL Server does not have a stored procedure "XP_SendMail" and I have not found the xp_sendmail SP... which is why I've been using the above... I thought about doing this in C# but wasn't sure if that would work as well as a sql job set to go off once a day.